# Can I run SonarQube code analysis for .NET Core (C#) on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, sonarqube, .net-core, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to execute and report a **SonarQube code analysis** (without test coverage for now) against a **.NET Core** project from a **Linux** build agent.

I downloaded `sonar-scanner` from [this page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner), and trying to run the report with the following command (the server url is set up in the configuration).

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey="MyProject" -Dsonar.projectName="MyProject" -Dsonar.sources=$PWD
```

The execution seems to be successful, I uploaded the full output to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/markvincze/cb5b61d2e1fc32fa71e088592df32604).

However, if I go to the project dashboard on the SonarQube site, I don't see any issues or code smells whatsoever.

[image]

I wanted to make sure that my project contains at least one error, so I added a `goto` statement to one of the source files, and checked if that warning is enabled in our Quality Profile, but I still get no issue.
(The sources files themselves are picked up correctly, I can see the list of files and all the source in SonarQube.)

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not expected to work?

*(Just to clarify that this is not a duplicate of the existing question about .NET Core: the same command I showed here works for me on Windows, it only does not work on Linux.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running SonarQube against an ASP.Net Core solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841439/running-sonarqube-against-an-asp-net-core-solution-project)

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed so you should see an error if run this way.

See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/535